# perform http request in overridden http method angular

Tags: angular, angular2-http

Hi I want to perform an http.get(...) in overridden request method of Http angular object.

```
@Injectable()
export class CustomHttp extends Http {
  constructor(backend: XHRBackend, options: RequestOptions, ) {
    super(backend, options);
  }

  request(url: string | Request, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
    //some logics
    if(//some conditions)
         super.get('url');
    return super.request(url, options).catch(this.catchError(this)); 
  }
}
```

The current behavior is skipping the http request into overridden request()

I'm using angular 4.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with the `super.get('url')` line?

Comment: Feels like an infinite loop

Comment: @torazaburo so I'm checking if token has been expired if true I send a get request to store new one

Answer (score 0):

Like it's done in https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/5293794316cc1b0f57d5d88b3fefdf6ae29d0d97/packages/http/src/http.ts#L113

```ts
return backend.createConnection(request).response;

private createRequest(backend: ConnectionBackend, request: Request): Observable<Response> {
  return backend.createConnection(request).response;
}

...

  let responseObservable: any;
  if(//some conditions)
    responseObservable = httpRequest(this._backend,
          new Request(mergeOptions(this._defaultOptions, options, RequestMethod.Get, <string>url)));
  }
  return responseObservable;
```